# Recursive Factorial Function - Displaying method

Tags: function, recursion, factorial

How would I display the method along with the answer?

e.g. User input = 5,

then the code output is "5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120" ?

```
function factorial(n)
{
    var result = n;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i ++)
    {
        result = i * result;
    }
    alert("The answer is " + result);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I don't see any recursion here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are looking to achieve is a string instead of an integer solution. So you should include logic to build this string inside your function.

You are also calculating the factorial incorrectly.

Something like this gives the desired output:

```
function factorial(n)
{
    var result = 1;
    var output_string = "";
    for (var i = n; i > 0; i --)
    {
        result *= i;
        if(i!=1) {
            output_string += i + " * ";
        } else {
            output_string += i;
        }
    }
    output_string += " = " + result;
    alert(output_string);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwpwb3yf/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you can do it using an optional parameter and a default value

- the bases cases for the factorial function are `n = 0` and `n = 1` where `factorial (n) = 1`
- in all other cases, `n * factorial (n - 1)`

We add a second parameter `acc` that serves as the *accumulator* for the factorial's final value. This allows us to simultaneously build the string result and compute the factorial's numerical answer using recursion.

```js
const factorial = (n, acc = 1) =>
  n < 2
    ? '1 = ' + acc
    : String (n) + ' * ' + factorial (n - 1, acc * n)

console.log (factorial (0))
// 1 = 1

console.log (factorial (1))
// 1 = 1

console.log (factorial (5))
// 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120

console.log (factorial (9))
// 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 362880
```

And that same function using ES6 string templates

```js
const factorial = (n, acc = 1) =>
  n < 2
    ? `1 = ${acc}`
    : `${n} * ${factorial (n - 1, acc * n)}`

console.log (factorial (0))
// 1 = 1

console.log (factorial (1))
// 1 = 1

console.log (factorial (5))
// 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120

console.log (factorial (9))
// 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 362880
```